# Command (insert) is not available for driver (Gd)

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04, gd, imagick, intervention

Hello Im working with Image Intervention. Project working very well from local server.
My remote server Digitalocean droplet and Lamp Ubuntu 14.04 installed. Im sure all necessary modules installed and active.

- GD Version => 2.1.1-dev
- imagick module version => 3.1.2
- PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21

Image::make('uploads/products/'.$filename)->fit(440, 585)->insert('uploads/watermark.png','center',0,0)->save('uploads/products/'.$filename, 100);

if **->insert** function bypass my codes working on droplet. but when add to **->insert** to code throwing error message.

Laravel 5.2 throw this error message: *Command (insert) is not available for driver (Gd)* Im trying all of my mind. how to fix this problem. I lost a one day :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
$file = $request->file('file');
list($filename, $extension) = explode(".", $file->getClientOriginalName());
$filename = strtolower(str_slug(uniqid().'-'.$filename).'.'.$extension);
$fileSave = $file->move('uploads/post',$filename);
Image::make('uploads/post/'.$filename)->fit(440, 585)->insert('uploads/watermark.png','center',0,0)->save('uploads/post/'.$filename, 60);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I before using Turkish locale settings on server. When I set to Turkish locale settings on any Ubuntu version. All small "i" characters changing big "İ" characters. you know right classnames on Laravel Framework. Every class names starting big characters. We dont need "İ" character working with developing codes.
This problem stole 3 days from my life. I am 12 times rebuilding to server. Im happy now !